# Why does Swift AVAudioPlayer not change state after MPRemoteCommandCenter play command?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

The environment for this is iOS 13.6 and Swift 5. I have a very simple app that successfully plays an MP3 file in the foreground or background. I added MPRemoteCommandCenter play and pause command handlers to it. I play the sound file in the foreground and then pause it.

When I tap the play button from the lock screen, my code calls audioPlayer.play(), which returns true. I hear the sound start playing again, but the currentTime of the player does not advance. After that, the play and pause buttons on the lock screen do nothing. When I foreground the app again, the play button plays from where it was before I went to the lock screen.

Here is my AudioPlayer class:

```
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class AudioPlayer: RemoteAudioCommandDelegate {
    
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    let remoteCommandHandler = RemoteAudioCommandHandler()
    
    var timer:Timer!

    func play(title: String) {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: title, ofType: "mp3")!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            audioPlayer =  try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            
            remoteCommandHandler.delegate = self
            remoteCommandHandler.enableDisableRemoteCommands(true)
            
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateNowPlayingInfo), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error = \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func play() {
        print ("audioPlayer.play() returned \(audioPlayer.play())")
    }
    
    func pause() {
        audioPlayer.pause()
    }
    
    func stop() {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
    
    func currentTime() -> TimeInterval {
        return audioPlayer.currentTime
    }
    
    func setCurrentTime(_ time:TimeInterval) {
        audioPlayer.currentTime = time
    }

    @objc func updateNowPlayingInfo() {
        // Hard-code the nowPlayingInfo since this is a simple test app

        var nowPlayingDict =
            [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Tin Man",
             MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle: "The Complete Greatest Hits",
             MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTrackNumber: NSNumber(value: UInt(10) as UInt),
             MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "America",
             MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: 208,
             MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: NSNumber(value: 1.0 as Float)] as [String : Any]
        
            nowPlayingDict[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = NSNumber(value: audioPlayer.currentTime as Double)
        
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingDict
    }
}
```

Here is my RemoteCommandHandler class:

```
import Foundation
import MediaPlayer

protocol RemoteAudioCommandDelegate: class {
    func play()
    func pause()
}

class RemoteAudioCommandHandler: NSObject {
    weak var delegate: RemoteAudioCommandDelegate?
    
    var remoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    var playTarget: Any? = nil
    var pauseTarget: Any? = nil
    
    func enableDisableRemoteCommands(_ enabled: Bool) {
        print("Called with enabled = \(enabled)")
        
        remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = enabled
        remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = enabled
        
        if enabled {
            addRemoteCommandHandlers()
        } else {
            removeRemoteCommandHandlers()
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func addRemoteCommandHandlers() {
        print( "Entered")
        
        if playTarget == nil {
            print( "Adding playTarget")
            playTarget = remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                print("addRemoteCommandHandlers calling delegate play")
                self.delegate?.play()
                return .success
            }
        }
        
        if pauseTarget == nil {
            print( "Adding pauseTarget")
            pauseTarget = remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                print("addRemoteCommandHandlers calling delegate pause")
                self.delegate?.pause()
                return .success
            }
        }

    }
    
    fileprivate func removeRemoteCommandHandlers() {
        print( "Entered")
        
        if playTarget != nil {
            print( "Removing playTarget")
            remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(playTarget)
            playTarget = nil
        }
        
        if pauseTarget != nil {
            print( "Removing pauseTarget")
            remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(pauseTarget)
            pauseTarget = nil
        }
    }

}
```

I will gladly supply further required info, because I'm baffled at why this relatively straightforward code (in my mind) code doesn't work.

Assistance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After some more debugging, I found that the AVAudioPlayer started to play the sound from the lock screen, but stopped again shortly after.

I mitigated the problem by adding a Timer. The timer checks if the last command by the user was play, but the sound is not playing. I also change the status when the user selects pause or the song stops playing at its natural end.

I am still at a loss for an actual fix for this problem.